# I need to make my program nested loops works simpler, since the operating time is maximum

Tags: python, list, numpy, for-loop, nested-loops

I am a learner in nested loops in python.

Problem:

Below I have written my code. I want to make my code  simpler, since when I run the code it takes so much time to produce the result.

My code:

I have a list which contains 1000 values:

```
Brake_index_values = [ 44990678,  44990679,  44990680,  44990681,  44990682,  44990683,
             44997076,  44990684,  44997077,  44990685,
            ...
             44960673,   8195083,   8979525, 100107546,  11089058,  43040161,
             43059162, 100100533,  10180192,  10036189]
```

I am storing the element no 1 in another list

```
original_top_brake_index = [Brake_index_values[0]]
```

I created a temporary list called temp and a numpy array for iteration through Loop:

```
temp =[]
arr = np.arange(0,1000,1)
```

Loop operation:

```
for i in range(1, len(Brake_index_values)):
    if top_15_brake <= 15:
        a1 = Brake_index_values[i]
        #a2 = Brake_index_values[j]
        a3 = arr[:i]
        for j in a3:
            a2 = range(Brake_index_values[j] - 30000, Brake_index_values[j] + 30000)
            if a1 in a2:
                pass
            else:
                temp.append(a1)
        if len(temp)== len(a3):
            original_top_brake_index.append(a1)
            top_15_brake += 1
            del temp[:]
        else:
            del temp[:]
            continue
```

What i did in the code:

I am comparing the `Brake_index_values[1]` element available between the range of 30000 before and after `Brake_index_values[0]` element, that is `range(Brake_index_values[0]-30000, Brake_index_values[0]+30000`)`.

If the `Brake_index_values[1]` available between the range, I should ignore that element and go for the next element `Brake_index_values[2`] and follow the same process as before for `Brake_index_values[0]` & `Brake_index_values[1]`

If it is available, store the Value, in `original_top_brake_index` thorough `append` operation.

The result I get:

It is working, but it takes so much time to complete the operation and sometimes it shows MemoryError.

Requirement:

I just want my code to work simpler and efficient with simple operations.

Request:

I am not a good coder, anyway I am sure that there will be some easy way to do the above process. Kindly shed some light to avoid this problem or a new way to approach.

Comment: I'm confused. So you check each element, and check if the element is between the range of the element value and 30000. If it is in the range, then that element is added to another list and if it isn't it is ignored. Is that right?

Comment: Yes you are right. @MohitMotwani
(Lets take 2 values a & b.
I am checking whether the value b is in range between (a-30000 to a+30000).
Possibility 1:
If b is in between (a-30000 to a+30000) , neglect that element by putting inside a temporary list. Then the same process continues with c (next element)
Possibility 2:
If b is not in b/w those range put b in another list called original_top_brake_index

Comment: Any answer @MohitMotwani ???

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at `numpy.where`
(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)
to get through this problem. Your code  will then look like:

```
BIV = np.array(Brake_index_values) # shortening for convenience
ref_val = BIV[0]
req_indicies, = np.where((BIV < ref_val-3e4) | (BIV > ref_val+3e4)) 
req_array = BIV[req_indicies]
```

This should give you an array of all the values passing the condition which you can further use.

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot able to get the actual answer what i expected....@Ash Sharma